# How to check if list of strings are present in command output in Ansible?

Tags: grep, ansible

I want to run an Ansible action on the condition that a shell command doesn't return the expected output. `ogr2ogr --formats` pretty-prints a list of compatible file formats. I want to grep the formats output, and if my expected file formats aren't in the output, I want to run a command to install these components. Does anyone know how to do this?

```
- name: check if proper ogr formats set up
  command: ogr2ogr --formats | grep $item
  with_items:
    - PostgreSQL
    - FileGDB
    - Spatialite
  register: ogr_check

# If grep from ogr_check didn't find a certain format from with_items, run this
- name: install proper ogr formats
  action: DO STUFF
  when: Not sure what to do here
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

First, please make sure you are using Ansible 1.3 or later. Ansible is still changing pretty quickly from what I can see, and a lot of awesome features and bug fixes are crucial.

As for checking, you can try something like this, taking advantage of `grep`'s exit code:

```
- name: check if proper ogr formats set up
  shell: ogr2ogr --formats | grep $item
  with_items:
    - PostgreSQL
    - FileGDB
    - Spatialite
  register: ogr_check
  # grep will exit with 1 when no results found. 
  # This causes the task not to halt play.
  ignore_errors: true

- name: install proper ogr formats
  action: DO STUFF
  when: ogr_check|failed
```

There are some other useful register variables, namely `item.stdout_lines`. If you'd like to see what's registered to the variable in detail, try the following task:

```
- debug: msg={{ogr_check}}
```

and then run the task in **double verbose** mode via `ansible-playbook my-playbook.yml -vv`. It will spit out a lot of useful dictionary values.

Comment: "ogr_check|failed" Filters are deprecated. Use: "ogr_check is failed" instead.

Answer (score 11):

My solution :

```
- name: "Get Ruby version"
command: "/home/deploy_user/.rbenv/shims/ruby -v"
changed_when: true
register: ruby_installed_version
ignore_errors: true

- name: "Installing Ruby 2.2.4"
command: '/home/deploy_user/.rbenv/libexec/rbenv install -v {{ruby_version}}'
become: yes
become_user: deployer
when: " ( ruby_installed_version | failed ) or ('{{ruby_version}}' not in ruby_installed_version.stdout) "
```